# On/Off Button to Activate function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to have the mouse hover function active only when my button is On and when my button is off have it not activate the hover function. I can get the hover to work but not when its on

```js
function changeBoxColor() {
  let myBox = document.getElementById("myBox");
  if (myBox.style.backgroundColor === "green") {
    myBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    myBox.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseover", changeBoxColor);
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseleave", changeBoxColor);

function changeToggleButton() {
  let toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
  if (toggleButton.value === "ON") {
    toggleButton.value = "OFF";
  } else {
    toggleButton.value = "ON";
  }
}
document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", changeToggleButton);
```

```html
<input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="ON">
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color: red;" id="myBox"></div>
```

Comment: You have code to change the value of the button, and code to handle the mouseover, but you never seem to combine them and check the button's value when mousing over the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like j08691 commented above, you just aren't binding the change in `EventListeners` on load, or change of the toggle button. Here is updated code that does exactly this:

```
function changeToggleButton() {
  let toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
  if (toggleButton.value === "ON") {
    toggleButton.value = "OFF";
    document.getElementById("myBox").removeEventListener("mouseover", changeBoxColor);
    document.getElementById("myBox").removeEventListener("mouseleave", changeBoxColor);
  } else {
    toggleButton.value = "ON";
    document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseover", changeBoxColor);
    document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseleave", changeBoxColor);
  }
}
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseover", changeBoxColor);
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseleave", changeBoxColor);
document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", changeToggleButton);
```

Now, this code assumes that the `toggleButton` starts as on, which is why we automatically `addEventListener` when the script is loaded. The other change is that when you check the `toggleButton.value`, we add/remove the `EventListener` from the element.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the events when the button value is 'ON', otherwise remove the events

```js
function changeBoxColor() {
  let myBox = document.getElementById("myBox");
  if (myBox.style.backgroundColor === "green") {
    myBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    myBox.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

   document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseover", changeBoxColor);
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener("mouseleave", changeBoxColor);

var eventOver = ["mouseover",changeBoxColor];
var eventLeave = ["mouseleave",changeBoxColor];


function changeToggleButton() {
  let toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggleButton");
  if (toggleButton.value === "ON") {
    toggleButton.value = "OFF";
     document.getElementById("myBox").removeEventListener(...eventOver);
document.getElementById("myBox").removeEventListener(...eventLeave);
    
  } else {
    toggleButton.value = "ON";
   document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener(...eventOver);
document.getElementById("myBox").addEventListener(...eventLeave);
  }
}
document.getElementById("toggleButton").addEventListener("click", changeToggleButton);
```

```html
<input id="toggleButton" type="button" value="ON">
<div style="height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color: red;" id="myBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this can be done using HTML and CSS only, if you accept that your 'toggle button' can be a checkbox (a checkbox basically is a toggle button).

You can then use an attribute selector to find the checkbox, or simply select it using its class or id. Then, using `+ div` and `+ div:hover`, you can style the div after it.

The trick is in this selector:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div:hover
```

Which basically says, target a hovered div, that is right after a checked input of type checkbox.

```css
input[type=checkbox] + div {
  height: 400px; 
  width: 400px; 
  background-color: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div:hover {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggleButton" type="checkbox" value="">
<div id="myBox"></div>
```

Of course, you can style the checkbox to look more like the button you want, or hide it completely and use a `<label for="toggleButton"></label>`, which can take the place of the checkbox visually, and be styled however you like.

Or, you can even use a normal button, and just change the class of the button on click. You can then still use CSS to style the div.

This could be done using `<input`, but you'd have to set the value through JavaScript. For the sake of example, I used `<button`, which has content rather than a value, and so you can toggle the caption as well using CSS, if you would like that.

```js
(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (element.classList.contains('on'))
      element.classList.remove('on');
    else
      element.classList.add('on');  
  });
})(document.getElementById('toggleButton'));
```

```css
button + div {
  height: 400px; 
  width: 400px; 
  background-color: red;
}

button.on + div:hover {
  background-color:green;
}

/* If you like, you can even set the button text in CSS, but
  beware of accessibility issues. */
button:after {
  content: "off";
}
button.on:after {
  content: "on";
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleButton" type="button"></button>
<div id="myBox"></div>
```